# How to SELECT rows in Azure SQL table containing '#' using PHP/SQL?

Tags: php, azure-sql-database

**Problem**

**TABLE NAME : imanity**

```
| name    | visibility | gender |
|---------|------------|--------|
| mark    | True       | M      |
| mark #1 | True       | M      |
| mark #2 | False      | M      |
```

I have an  AZURE SQL table containing this information (not real). The problem is when I tried to filter to mark #2, AZURE  SQL just straight up doesn't filter to the correct row or return all the row with the name mark. I will be doing this in PHP but for now, I am just trying out with AZURE SQL.

**Here are some commands that I have tried**

```
1. SELECT visibility FROM imanity where name LIKE 'mark #2';
2. SELECT visibility FROM imanity where name LIKE '%mark #2%';
3. SELECT visibility FROM imanity where name LIKE '%[mark #2]%';
```

**Question**
Is there any solution? Thanks.

I have edited my problem to be more specific. Pardon if I forgot to mentioned that it is **azure sql database**

Comment: What are the result of first and second queries? It seems that `name = 'mark #2'` and `name LIKE '%mark #2%'` should return only the row containing `mark #2`

Comment: The response I got was `Affected rows: 0` . This means that the command didnt filter.

Comment: @CreamyOreo, not able to replicate your problem. It is working fine for me. [Check fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=af0418b1d96e6e85f7cd706189cd36a2). what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy I don't have any idea. My problem is literally I cant filter when I use the command as above. **Coding is magic**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a table like you:
[image]

I tested all code in my Azure SQL database with SSMS, every thing works ok.
[image]

I use SSMS 17.9.1.

[image]

I think your problem is the `LIKE` query doesn't work(`name='mark #2'` should works).

Some suggestions is you can test theses SQL statements in different tool, like Portal Azure SQL database Query Editor(preview).
[image]

Let's say you use SSMS,  if these query works well in Query Editor or other database managed tools, it should also works with PHP, there must be somethings wrong with SSMS, maybe you need update it to newest version or re-install it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am also not too sure what is the issue. It is because when I tried to filter with PHP it works but not when I am using the query editor in the website

Comment: what happens if  u set name to primary key ? does it still work?

Comment: According to the docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/filter-published-data?view=sql-server-ver15

They quoted " if a primary key column is present, it cannot be filtered" so how do you get it to filter ? 

because i tried your way in php i couldnt get it to work

Comment: I didn't test in PHP. I recreate the table and add primary key to name,  run the sql statement in SSMS with no error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT visibility FROM imanity where name LIKE '%#%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT visibility FROM imanity where name='mark #2';
```

Answer (score 0):

As per given database values, query can be

```
SELECT visibility FROM imanity where name like '%mark #%';
```

it will result all results which contains `mark #` so as per above given database data. it will return last 2 records.